# TypeScript Library import another library

Tags: javascript, npm, es6-modules

I'm developing a library in TypeScript.

This library uses the https://github.com/Simonwep/pickr library.

I would like to make my library available so users can use it, but question is: do I need to bundle pickr library or just put a reference in the package.json?
I tried to use the library in a sample project and in dev mode all works since it loads from node_modules, but when I build the project and try to load it fails to load it.
It works only by importing the library using

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@simonwep/pickr/dist/pickr.min.js"></script>
```

If library will be used in a web browser I made it so the script tag is automatically added.

But what if someone will use the library in an ionic project for instance which will run on a tablet?
In this case Pickr library needs to bundled in the final build.

Is this an automatic process? What's the correct way of using a third-party library in this case?

Answer (score 0):

If you want pickr to get bundled with your code you will have to

1. List it under dependencies
2. Import it in your code (see pickr docs)

If its not imported in your code it wont be bundled.

If you want to tell the user to manually add pickr when he uses your module you can list pickr as a peerDependency in your package.json

Comment: Thanks, but what's the best way in this case? If for instance library will be used with cordova, in this case pickr need to be bundled. So do I need to do or users using the library will need to make sure pickr is imported correctly?